# ORA-00918 column ambiguously defined using JPA

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, ambiguous

I'm having this problem "ORA-00918" using JPA, this is part of my entity where the problem is:

```
@ManyToOne
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "INSTITUCION_ID", referencedColumnName = "INSTITUCION_ID", nullable = false),
    @JoinColumn(name = "UNIDADGESTORARH_ID", referencedColumnName = "UNIDADGESTORARH_ID", nullable = false),
    @JoinColumn(name = "IDPERSONA", referencedColumnName = "IDPERSONA", nullable = false)
})
RhPersonaUrhis rhPersonaUrhis;

@ManyToOne
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "INSTITUCION_ID", referencedColumnName = "INSTITUCION_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false),
    @JoinColumn(name = "UNIDADGESTORARH_ID", referencedColumnName = "UNIDADGESTORARH_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false),
    @JoinColumn(name = "IDHABDESC", referencedColumnName = "IDHABDESC", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
})
CrhHabdescInstit crhHabdescInstit;

@Column(length = 6, nullable = false)
@Size(max = 6, min = 1)
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
String idhabdesc;
```

As you see guys i have two composite @JoinColumns that use the fields INSTITUCION_ID and UNIDADGESTORARH_ID and as we know in one of both @JoinColumns has to be mark with insertable = false, updatable = false and if we mark one joincolumn all of them have to make insertable = false, updatable = false

That forced me to add a @Column field, called "idhabdesc" to be capable to persist in oracle and it works, but the problem is when i make a find using this entity throws the error. Can you help please?

Thank you so much

Comment: The data model is a mess, but I guess you are trying to match an existing database? You are defining the same column twice, once as a join column and once as a normal column. That doesn't work. One simple workaround would be to remove the many-to-one relations and get them manually (find with primary key or join with JPQL). That way you can side-step the (as far as I know) unsupported scenario with relations that share the same leading columns.

Comment: Exactly, i'm trying to match an existing database that is a mess (you're totally right), these people who i work for don't understand about JPA they just focus to create constraints in database that make it a mess. Thank you, i just thought that there could be a way to do what i want with this mess